# Does YugaByte Supports deployment in RedHat OpenShift 3.9 env?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat

Can We deploy Yugabyte in Redhat OpenShift kubernetes env 3.9, do we have Support for it ? do we have any reference model for the deployment in OpenShift ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use helm charts to deploy Yugabyte DB in Redhat OpenShift, the instructions for this are here: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/deploy/kubernetes/helm-chart/

Does that work for you?